# nodejs da erro e para servidor apos 2 minutos

Tags: node.js, express.js

Boa noite pessoal tenho um programinha básico que até ontem tava de boa, hoje a tarde começou a da erro na execução do "nodemon app" ou somente o "node app"

segue o erro:

> throw er // unhandled 'error' event error: read ECONNRESET    at
>   _errnoExecmption (util.js:992:11    at TCP.onread (net.js:618:25)

Pesquisando todos falam que é por conta da porta ta em uso por outro processo, porém nao acredito, pois o servidor sobe e para apos 2 minutos, OBS.. 2 minutos sem eu mexer no sistema se eu tiver usando o sistema ele nao para. 
Até cronometrei. Com o nodemon ele fica parado num mensagem em vermelho
dizendo que está aguardando por uma correção. já desfiz as ultimas alterações que adicionei no sistema, que foi uma chamada pra uma tela de pesquisa atraves de um fomulario via post (tava funcionando de boa a pesquisa).

Alguém tem noção o que pode ser??

abaixo deixo meu app.js (bem básico)

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var path = require('path');

var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

require('./config/passport')(passport); // passo o  passport para configuração

//configurar nossa aplicação express

app.use(morgan('dev')); // registrar cada pedido para o console
app.use(cookieParser()); // ler cookies (necessários para autenticação)
//app.use(bodyParser()); // obter informações de formulários html

//ver configuração do motor
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(expressLayouts);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'SessaoSecreta...',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // sessões de login persistentes
app.use(flash()); // use o flash de conexão para mensagens flash armazenadas na sessão

require('./config/routes.js')(app, passport); // carregar nossas rotas e passar em nosso aplicativo e passaporte totalmente configurado

app.listen(port);

console.log('  ');
console.log('Conectado em ===>  ' + port);
console.log('  ');
console.log('  ');


//pegar 404 e encaminhar para manipulador de erro
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).render('404', { title: "Desculpe, página nao encontrada", session: req.sessionbo });
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).render('404', { title: "Desculpe, página nao encontrada" });
});

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Precisando de mais informações to por aqui pessoal, obrigado!!
at+

Comment: Tem vários problemas aparente no seu código, você esta dando um listen na porta e exportando o app e  o modulo, os middleware de erro status 500 também estão em uma posição incorreta, devem ficar depois das rotas e antes do listen. Qual o motivo de exportar o app? Não use ambos os exports. Eu criei um repositório para eu não ter que ficar criando a estrutura do zero da uma olhada [Github](https://github.com/andersonmendesdev/apibase-node-babel)

Comment: opa, vou sim obg!!, sobre o servidor parar, descobri que é o mysql quando acesso ele hospedando em algum servidor na web, qndo é localhost ele segura, vou olhar o repositorio obg!